# Why my program crashes when I declare this two variables?

Tags: c, variables, interpreter

I'm trying to make an interpreter using C programming language, it works well, but when I try to add these two variables in the code, the program just crashes.
Fortunately, when I add the static keyword or I leave the variables as global in the program, the program doesn't crash.
Why does this happen ?
Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>

#include <windows.h>

//If I leave the variables here the program doesn't crash
//int esMain = 0;
//int esEnd = 0;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
FILE *f;

f = fopen(argv[1], "r+");


if(f == NULL){
    perror("Error: No se encuentra el archivo\nDescripcion");
    exit(1);
}

if(ferror(f)){
    printf("Archivo corrupto");
    exit(1);
}

printf("\nEjecutando archivo: %s\n\n\n", argv[1]);



int esMain = 0;//These two variables makes the program to crash
int esEnd = 0;

//But if I add the static keyword in both variables the program works well.

char* str;

while(1){

    fgets(str, 25, f);

    if(strncmp(str, "MAIN:", 5) == 0){
            esMain = 1;
    }

    if(strncmp(str, "END.", 4) == 0){
            esEnd = 1;
    }

    if(feof(f) != 0){
        if(esMain == 0){
            printf("No existe el parametro main, cierre por no tener el parametro main (poner MAIN: ENCIMA)");
            exit(1);
        }
        if(esEnd == 0){
            printf("No existe el parametro end, cierre por no tener el parametro main (poner END. ENCIMA)");
            exit(1);
        }
        break;
    }
}

rewind(f);

while(1){
    fgets(str, 500, f);

    if(strncmp(str, "print ", 6) == 0){
        printf(str + 6);
    }

    if(strncmp(str, "msg", 3) == 0){
        if(strstr(str + 4, "check")){
            MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP, str + 10, "Check", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        }

        if(strstr(str + 4, "error")){
            MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP, str + 10, "Error", MB_ICONERROR);
        }
    }

    if(strncmp(str, "pause", 5) == 0){
        getch();
    }

    if(feof(f) != 0){
        break;
    }


}

printf("\n\n\nEND EXECUTION");

fclose(f);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char* str;` This is an uninitialized pointer which does not point anywhere in particular, yet `fgets(str, 25, f);` attempts to write to it, which is [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). Make `str` point to a valid string buffer before using it, for example `char str[25];` or `char *str = malloc(25);`.

Comment: if you choose the path of dynamic memory allocation by `malloc`, remember to also `free(str)` at the end of the program, you may also want to cast the return value of malloc to `char*`, as by standard it returns `void*`

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings to help catch these simple errors.

Comment: `if(feof(f) != 0){` is too late.  Use `while(fgets(str, 500, f)) {`

Comment: `printf(str + 6);` is a fertile ground for a hacker exploit as `printf()` first expects a _format_ string.  Use `printf("%s", str + 6);`

Comment: Thank y'all for your recommendations <3 :),  it really helps me to understand more better this beautiful language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `char* str;` declaration is probably what is breaking your code. When you declare it as global it is stored in a different place in memory than if you declare it inside a function.

You got **lucky** to have your program working with it as global variable. Since you haven't reserved any place in memory, the variable is accessing some memory that it shouldn't (undefined behavior). **Lucky** might not be the best word to describe because due to t his undefined behavior you might think that your program is working correctly, which is not (If it had crashed you would be 100% that there were errors).

What you can do to fix that is one of the following:

1. allocate it dynamically: `char *str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*25);`
2. change it to br an array: `char str[25];`
3. point to an existing array: `char arr[25]; char *str = arr;`

Comment: Cast not need.  Consider `str = malloc(sizeof *str * 25)` to avoid mis-matching the type.

Comment: Honestly my compiler didn't gave any errors.
I'm using GCC (MinGW).